# Nearby Connections 2.0: simultaneous connection requests fail on both devices

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I am working on a P2P chat application where I connect with devices and save their info in local Room database. Every time the app is launched, I start advertising and discovering (at the same time) in order to see other nearby devices but also be seen by other devices in order to reconnect to the ones I have already connected once (the ones that are saved inside the DB). Now the problem is that both devices detect each other triggering onEndpointFound callback inside which they both perform a connection request to the other device by calling requestConnection. The problem is that both calls on both devices fail and the connection is not initiated from any device as I read that should happen here: [Nearby Connections 2.0: Both sides request connections, but don't successfully connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510187/nearby-connections-2-0-both-sides-request-connections-but-dont-successfully-c)

I was wondering if there is a problem with the API being buggy or if I am doing something wrong. Here is how I handle reconnection in my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String SERVICE_ID = "com.example.snakemessenger";

    public static AppDatabase db;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;

    private static final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS =
            new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            };

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = 1;

    public static final Strategy STRATEGY = Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER;

    public static String codeName;

    public static boolean discovering;

    public static Map<String, String> pendingConnectionsData;

    private EndpointDiscoveryCallback endpointDiscoveryCallback =
            new EndpointDiscoveryCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onEndpointFound(@NonNull final String endpointId, @NonNull final DiscoveredEndpointInfo info) {
                    String endpointPhone = info.getEndpointName();

                    Log.d(TAG, "onEndpointFound: found device with endpointId " + endpointId + " and phone " + endpointPhone);

                    Contact contact = db.getContactDao().findByPhone(endpointPhone);

                    if (contact != null && !contact.isConnected()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onEndpointFound: device is in local DB. Sending connection request...");

                        Nearby.getConnectionsClient(getApplicationContext()).requestConnection(codeName, endpointId, connectionLifecycleCallback)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onEndpointFound: connection request successfully sent");
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                MainActivity.this,
                                                "There was a problem reconnecting to " + info.getEndpointName() + ".",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                        ).show();
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onEndpointFound: failed to send connection request. Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onEndpointLost(@NonNull String endpointId) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onEndpointLost: device with endpointId " + endpointId + " went outside communication range.");
                }
            };

    private final ConnectionLifecycleCallback connectionLifecycleCallback =
            new ConnectionLifecycleCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionInitiated(@NonNull final String endpointId, @NonNull final ConnectionInfo connectionInfo) {
                    final String endpointPhone = connectionInfo.getEndpointName();

                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionInitiated: initiated connection with device having endpointId " + endpointId + " and phone " + endpointPhone);

                    final Contact contact = db.getContactDao().findByPhone(endpointPhone);

                    if (contact != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionInitiated: Device is in local DB. Updating endpointId...");
                        contact.setEndpointID(endpointId);
                        db.getContactDao().updateContact(contact);
                        pendingConnectionsData.put(endpointId, connectionInfo.getEndpointName());

                        Nearby.getConnectionsClient(getApplicationContext()).acceptConnection(endpointId, payloadCallback)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionInitiated: Successfully accepted reconnection request for device");
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        pendingConnectionsData.remove(endpointId);
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                MainActivity.this,
                                                "Failed to reconnect to " + endpointPhone + ".",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                        ).show();
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionInitiated: Couldn't accept reconnection request for device");
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionInitiated: Unrecognized device, adding request to connection requests...");
                        connectionRequests.add(new ConnectionRequest(endpointId, connectionInfo.getEndpointName()));
                        mTabLayout.getTabAt(3).getOrCreateBadge().setNumber(connectionRequests.size());
                        mTabLayout.getTabAt(3).getOrCreateBadge().setVisible(true);
                        pendingConnectionsData.put(endpointId, connectionInfo.getEndpointName());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionResult(String endpointId, ConnectionResolution result) {
                    String endpointPhone = pendingConnectionsData.get(endpointId);

                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionResult: result connection with device having endpointId " + endpointId + " and phone " + endpointPhone);

                    Contact contact = db.getContactDao().findByPhone(endpointPhone);

                    if (result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == ConnectionsStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionResult: the connection is established");
                        if (contact == null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionResult: connected to a new device");
                            db.getContactDao().addContact(new Contact(0, endpointPhone, endpointPhone, endpointId, true));
                            removeConnectionRequest(endpointId);
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionResult: reconnected to an old device");
                            contact.setConnected(true);
                            db.getContactDao().updateContact(contact);
                        }
                    } else if (result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == ConnectionsStatusCodes.STATUS_ERROR) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                "There was an error connecting with" + pendingConnectionsData.get(endpointId) + ".",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show();

                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionResult: couldn't establish a connection between devices");
                    }

                    pendingConnectionsData.remove(endpointId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(@NonNull String endpointId) {
                    Contact contact = db.getContactDao().findById(endpointId);
                    contact.setConnected(false);
                    db.getContactDao().updateContact(contact);

                    Toast.makeText(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            contact.getName() + " disconnected.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();

                    Log.d(TAG, "onDisconnected: device with endpointId " + endpointId + " and phone " + contact.getPhone() + " disconnected.");
                }
            };

    private PayloadCallback payloadCallback =
            new PayloadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPayloadReceived(@NonNull String endpointId, @NonNull Payload payload) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPayloadTransferUpdate(@NonNull String endpointId, @NonNull PayloadTransferUpdate payloadTransferUpdate) {

                }
            };

    public static List<ConnectionRequest> connectionRequests;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle("Snake Messenger");
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        connectionRequests = new ArrayList<>();
        pendingConnectionsData = new HashMap<>();

        db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "SnakeMessengerDB")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: initialized Room DB");

        loginPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("LOGIN_DETAILS", MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean signedIn = loginPreferences.getBoolean("signedIn", false);

        if (!signedIn) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: user is not signed in. Sending him to login activity...");
            sendUserToLoginActivity();
        }

        codeName = loginPreferences.getString("phone", "");

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: user is signed in and will advertise using codeName " + codeName);

        ViewPager2 mViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_pager);
        mViewPager2.setAdapter(new TabsAccessorAdapter(this));

        mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
        TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(mTabLayout, mViewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        tab.setText("Chats");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tab.setText("Groups");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tab.setText("Contacts");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tab.setText("Requests");

                        BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = tab.getOrCreateBadge();
                        badgeDrawable.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.red));

                        if (!connectionRequests.isEmpty()) {
                            badgeDrawable.setNumber(connectionRequests.size());
                            badgeDrawable.setVisible(true);
                        } else {
                            badgeDrawable.setVisible(false);
                        }

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        tabLayoutMediator.attach();

        if (!hasPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: app does not have all the required permissions. Requesting permissions...");

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }

        startAdvertising();
        startDiscovering();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopAdvertising();
        stopDiscovering();
        Nearby.getConnectionsClient(getApplicationContext()).stopAllEndpoints();
        db.getContactDao().disconnectContacts();

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void startAdvertising() {
        AdvertisingOptions advertisingOptions =
                new AdvertisingOptions.Builder().setStrategy(STRATEGY).build();
        Nearby.getConnectionsClient(getApplicationContext())
                .startAdvertising(
                        codeName, SERVICE_ID, connectionLifecycleCallback, advertisingOptions)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "startAdvertising: successfully started advertising");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was a problem starting advertising.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "startAdvertising: couldn't start advertising.Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

    public void stopAdvertising() {
        Nearby.getConnectionsClient(getApplicationContext()).stopAdvertising();
        Log.d(TAG, "stopAdvertising: stopped advertising");
    }

    public void startDiscovering() {
        DiscoveryOptions discoveryOptions =
                new DiscoveryOptions.Builder().setStrategy(MainActivity.STRATEGY).build();
        Nearby.getConnectionsClient(getApplicationContext())
                .startDiscovery(MainActivity.SERVICE_ID, endpointDiscoveryCallback, discoveryOptions)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "startDiscovering: started discovering");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                "There was a problem starting discovering.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "startDiscovering: couldn't start discovering. Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        discovering = true;
    }

    public void stopDiscovering() {
        Nearby.getConnectionsClient(getApplicationContext()).stopDiscovery();
        discovering = false;

        Log.d(TAG, "stopDiscovering: stopped discovering");
    }

    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @CallSuper
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE_REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS) {
            return;
        }

        for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
            if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Missing permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }

        recreate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_settings_option) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected: settings option selected");
            sendUserToSettingsActivity();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_sign_out_option) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected: sign out option selected");
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = loginPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("signedIn", false);
            editor.apply();
            sendUserToLoginActivity();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void sendUserToSettingsActivity() {
        Log.d(TAG, "sendUserToSettingActivity: starting settings activity...");
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
    }

    private void sendUserToLoginActivity() {
        Log.d(TAG, "sendUserToLoginActivity: starting login activity...");
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void removeConnectionRequest(String endpointId) {
        Iterator<ConnectionRequest> it = connectionRequests.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = it.next();

            if (connectionRequest.getSenderID().equals(endpointId)) {
                it.remove();
                Log.d(TAG, "removeConnectionRequest: removed connection request coming from device with endpointId " + endpointId);
            }
        }

        if (!connectionRequests.isEmpty()) {
            mTabLayout.getTabAt(3).getOrCreateBadge().setNumber(connectionRequests.size());
        } else {
            mTabLayout.getTabAt(3).getOrCreateBadge().setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Logcat of both devices I am testing the app on. I am using a Samsung Galaxy S10+ and a Samsung Galaxy Tab A both running Android 10.

Samsung Galaxy S10+ logcat:

```
2020-07-29 14:48:30.695 25915-25915/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: onCreate: initialized Room DB
2020-07-29 14:48:30.702 25915-25915/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: onCreate: user is signed in and will advertise using codeName 0768803341
2020-07-29 14:48:32.505 25915-25915/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: startAdvertising: successfully started advertising
2020-07-29 14:48:32.562 25915-25915/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: startDiscovering: started discovering
2020-07-29 14:48:48.259 25915-25915/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: onEndpointFound: found device with endpointId sKZ6 and phone 0748489006
2020-07-29 14:48:48.308 25915-25915/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: onEndpointFound: device is in local DB. Sending connection request...
2020-07-29 14:49:09.000 25915-25915/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: onEndpointFound: failed to send connection request. Error: 8012: STATUS_ENDPOINT_IO_ERROR
```

Samsung Galaxy Tab A logcat:

```
2020-07-29 14:48:40.517 29794-29794/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: startAdvertising: successfully started advertising
2020-07-29 14:48:40.974 29794-29794/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: startDiscovering: started discovering
2020-07-29 14:48:43.737 29794-29794/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: onEndpointFound: found device with endpointId oy54 and phone 0768803341
2020-07-29 14:48:43.839 29794-29794/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: onEndpointFound: device is in local DB. Sending connection request...
2020-07-29 14:49:06.393 29794-29794/com.example.snakemessenger D/MainActivity: onEndpointFound: failed to send connection request. Error: 8012: STATUS_ENDPOINT_IO_ERROR
```

Also, here is my build.gradle file, in case I am missing something here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.snakemessenger"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    def room_version = "2.2.5"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**UPDATE**

After some more research I noticed that sometimes devices manage to connect, so I decided to stop discovery whenever a requestConnection call fails, wait for 3 seconds and restart discovery, by doing something like this:

```
Nearby.getConnectionsClient(getApplicationContext()).requestConnection(codeName, endpointId, connectionLifecycleCallback)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onEndpointFound: connection request successfully sent");
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onEndpointFound: failed to send connection request. Error: " + e.getMessage());

                                        stopDiscovering();

                                        Runnable startDiscoveryAgain = new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                startDiscovering();
                                            }
                                        };

                                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                                        handler.postDelayed(startDiscoveryAgain, 3000);
                                    }
                                });
```

Is this solution good or is there a better workaround than this?

Comment: I was also facing this issue. The problem comes when both devices try to connect at the same time. The good thing with a nearby connection is we can send and retrieve endpoint information. In my app, I put user creation time in the endpoint information. Now when both devices discover each other at the same time, the new user's device waits for e.g., 2 seconds to request a connection while the old user's device instantly requests a connection. My app keeps discovering other devices when it's open and has not faced any issues yet in testing.