# Google nearby api 12.0.1 with android things stable release 1.0 throws 8007 STATUS_BLUETOOTH_ERROR

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-things, google-nearby, android-things-console

I am using NearBy 2.0 API version `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:12.0.1'` with android things `'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'` to create a smart home app, but previously upto 8th may it was working fine with the build downloaded from android things console, but from yesterday it is throwing `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException:8007 STATUS_BLUETOOTH_ERROR`. when I am starting advertisement or discovery whichever maybe. But if I use the previous build (image with apk) of 8th may it is working fine. I tried with that old apk also like new os image with old apk, found not working. In logcat I found it is unable to start listening for incoming connections.

I searched SO and google a lot but no solution worked. Even followed this [Error codes in Nearby Connections 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036191/error-codes-in-nearby-connections-2-0/46328410) but no luck. I am using Raspberry PI 3 model B.
 Help!!

Comment: some serial downvoter got interest in my SO profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it working , actually when I was configuring the hardware during the build preparation in android things console there I used Starter Kit configuration which by default configured `UART` as `UART0 (disables Bluetooth)` , hence the exception it was throwing `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException:8007 STATUS_BLUETOOTH_ERROR.` during init of nearby where I was starting advertisement.
So the fix is change the configuration of `UART` to `MINIUART` in android things console and create the build.

Answer (score 1):

Android Things 1 comes [bundled with Google Play Services 12.5.20](https://developer.android.com/things/versions/releases). Try updating your dependencies and see if anything changes.

Comment: I tried with `11.6.2`,`11.8.0`,`12.0.1` and `15.x.x` all these versions of dependencies but no luck. But if I use the previous build (image with apk) of 8th may and on top of that if I install the app via android studio with any of the dependency version mentioned above it is working fine.! 
Hence , this is ok as long as I have that image(8th may),in case if I loose it then my development stops. Also because of this I cant test OTA update properly as Nearby is a vital part in my app. Please suggest !

Comment: I will look into the hardware configuration when creating the build in android things consol,cause I saw `UART UART0 (disables Bluetooth)` this I will change to `MINIUART` and if works will comment here.